# What is the term or theory to explain adopting behaviors when hurt by someone else

Tags: social-psychology, personality, personality-disorder

I have been trying to search for a term or theory to explain adopting behaviors when bad / hurtful things happen to a person. For example, if a person is abused and ends up being an abuser because it happened to them, even if it is a maladaptation.

So if this [ABC article](https://abcnews.go.com/Primetime/parents-struggle-break-cycle-abuse/story?id=8549642) that says 1/3 of people that are abused become abusers, what is the mechanism, or term, for this?

I am asking because someone I know adopts bad behaviors when they happen to them once or twice, and justify it as 'that is how the world works'. I'm trying to understand why this happens so quickly for this person from clearly outlying events.

Comment: I will try and find a reference or 2 but the risk levels of abused becoming abusers is very low. Those who do are those who have not been able to reconcile their problems through therapy.

Comment: As for a term or theory, there is the "circle of abuse", or "abuse circle" or "cycle of abuse", but many talk of this where the abused find themselves in a circle within life where they later develop relationships with other abusive people

Comment: *"Roughly one in 10 male victims of child sex abuse in a U.K. study later went on to abuse children as adults."* Source: [WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/mental-health/news/20030206/do-sexually-abused-kids-become-abusers). The study is in The Lancet (Free) at https://doi.org/10.1016/S0140-6736(03)12501-9

Comment: How in the world do you find out (systematically) whether someone abused children?  If there’s no criminal record, who are they asking? Can’t believe that’s the lancet.  Wow. Bye bye lancet.